# Group an array of dictionary by key in Swift4 - CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, grouping, swift4

I am parsing my JSON response and saving it to CoreData. I am fetching the data using `NSFetchedResultsController` this way:

```
func getTablesForOutlet(managedObjectContext:NSManagedObjectContext) -> NSFetchedResultsController<TablesEntity> {
    let fetchedResultController: NSFetchedResultsController<TablesEntity>

    let request: NSFetchRequest<TablesEntity> = TablesEntity.fetchRequest()
    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "section", ascending: true)
    request.sortDescriptors = [sort]

    fetchedResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    do {
        try fetchedResultController.performFetch()
        tablesArray = fetchedResultController.fetchedObjects!


        let predicate = { (element: TablesEntity) in
            return element.section
        }

        let dictionary = Dictionary(grouping: tablesArray, by: predicate)

        tableCollectionView.reloadData()

    }
    catch {
        fatalError("Error in fetching records")
    }


    return fetchedResultController
}
```

In Swift4, apple introduced an initialise method for a `Dictionary` called `init(grouping:by:)` but it does not work on my `tablesArray`.

I get the error `Cannot convert value of type '(TablesEntity) -> String?' to expected argument type '(_) -> _` on the line `let dictionary = Dictionary(grouping: tablesArray, by: predicate)`.

Any ideas on how to get this work?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `NSFetchedResultsController` provides functionality to group data by using the `sectionNameKeyPath` parameter (even in Swift 3 and earlier). The `Dictionary(grouping` way doesn't work.

Comment: What if you make your predicate to return String instead of optional?

Comment: @vadian In my fetchRequest , if I change sectionNameKeyPath from nil to "section", I get the array of sections like var sectionInfo = fetchedResultController.sections . But how do I group my tablesArray with the above sections?

Comment: Please read the documentation of `NSFetchedResultsController`, you have  to add also an appropriate (section) sort descriptor.